# Probability: 12 students choose a major

Tags: probability, combinatorics

12 students must choose a major from 6 options (math, biology, physics, chemistry, psychology and architecture).

a) what is the probability that exactly 3 students choose physics?

b) what is the probability that each major "receives" 2 students?

My thoughts:

a) there are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to choose the 3 students. Now, each of the other stundents can choose from 5 majors, so there are $5^9$ ways. There are $6^{12}$ ways the students can choose their major, so the probability is $\frac{\binom{12}{3}\times 5^9}{6^{12}}= 0.1974$

b) There are $\frac{12!}{2!^6}$ ways of dividing the 12 students in groups of 2, so the probability is $\frac{12!}{2!^6}\over{6^{12}}$$=0.0034$. Is this right?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: I read it over as well.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, your calculations are correct. Ideally, you should have mentioned that the students choose their majors independently uniformly at random.